# In a elliptic coordinate system,is there any existing solution for Laplace equation?

Tags: special-functions, harmonic-functions

In a cylindrical system,Bessel function plays a role. And In a spherical system ,Legendre polynomials works in Laplace equations.
   Is there any solution for Laplace equation in a elliptic system? Special cases can also be OK.

Comment: Likely the Mathieu functions would be involved.

Comment: Welcome to Math StackExchange, @W.Q.Zhang!  Could you explain your problem a bit more?  The solution to Laplace's equation does not depend on the coordinate system used (although it may be expressed differently in different coordinates), but it does depend on the domain.  Are you considering an elliptical domain?

Comment: @Strants ,thanks. Yes,an elliptical domain is considered.